# Allow Download from a GCP Bucket to a Specific Users Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to give a group of users a download permission to download files from a specific GCP Bucket. I created that group and gave it "Storage Legacy Object Reader" role but still have a 403 error.

What I want is to just allow the company authenticated users to download and not using the allAuthenticatedUsers nor allUsers.

Any thoughts on how to do that.

Comment: How does the user in your company access the files? Do you have a pattern of URL? or a process to describe?

Comment: Actually the files are generated by another tool which then sends the http download links to the internal users for download. The links are of the default pattern provided by the bucket service, something like: 
"htttps://storage.cloud.google.com/downloads-bucket/parent-folder/child-folder/the-file-long-name.csv"

Comment: Did you try to grant the role storage object viewer on the group?

Comment: No, because that will give them the privilege to list the contents of the bucket. I want them just to download with the role "Storage Legacy Object Reader"

Answer (score 0):

For specific users to download files from specific GCP bucket, you may want to:

1. Enable [bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-uniform-bucket-level-access) for that specific bucket.
2. [Add the desired role to the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions).

With regards to IAM roles, I suggest either of the [following](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) but will still depend on your needs:

1. [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) - Grants full control of buckets and objects. When applied to an individual bucket, control applies only to the specified bucket and objects within the bucket.
2. [Storage Object Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) - Grants full control over objects, including listing, creating, viewing, and deleting objects.